# How do I create a new taskbar link for a webpage?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts

How can I create a taskbar link to a webpage (ie Windows Live Mail) to launch the new Windows Live utility that has replaced Hotmail ? Any help would be appreciated and Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With Internet Explorer this is easy. Just drag the tab for the site to the Taskbar till you see this:

[image: 1]

When you drop the site's tab onto the Taskbar you'll end up pinning it like this:

[image: 2]

Creating "application shortcuts" is equally easy with Chrome via `Chrome menu / Tools / Create application shortcuts`. See [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710) for more.

Other browsers that do not support pinning can generally be invoked with the site's URL from the command line. So an alternate solution would be to create a normal shortcut to the browser's executable (say Firefox.exe), and in the shortcut properties **Target** field you just tack on the URL like so:

[image: 3]

Now pin this shortcut to the Taskbar. If you want you can further customise the shortcut by downloading the site's favicon (generally `http://www.site.com/favicon.ico`) and setting it as the shortcut's icon.